# Making a template function use the float type internally if instanciated as an integer type

Tags: c++, templates, types

I am working on a C++ class template "Layer" which is essentially just an interpretation of a 2d-array.

The function "gradient(min, max, axis)" is already implemented, but works only on floating point types due to some division operations.
Instead of creating a version for integer types (which would create a lot of **duplicated code**) my plan is to alter the function as follows:

- Check if we are being called on an floating point type (float, double, long double)
- if yes: Calculate the gradient as the given floating point type
- if not: Calculate the gradient as a float and convert it back to the integer type
- save the gradient to memory

In theory the implementation would look something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void Layer<T>::gradient(T value_min, T value_max, Axis axis){
    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>){
        typename X = T;     //use datatype instantiated with if it is a floating point
    } else{
        typename X = float; //use float instead when called on integers
    }
    X value_min_new = (X) value_min;
    X value_max_new = (X) value_max;

    //functions to generate gradient, doesn't work on integers
    //many lines of code, but basically:
    Library::DataClass<X> gradient = generateGradient(value_min_new, value_max_new, axis);

    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>) {
        Library::storeDataToMemory(gradient);
    }else{
        Library::DataClass<T> gradientCast = Library::cast(gradient);
        Library::storeDataToMemory(gradientCast);
    }
}
```

But of course i can't just create a variable holding a data type like in that first if-statement. Any idea how to solve this problem? I have to use "Library" and its functions, which rules out many alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [std::conditional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
using X = std::conditional_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T, float>;
```